# Algorithm to find and add prime numbers

Tags: algorithms, primes

How would one write code to find and add the prime numbers between 4 and 5 million? I need a code that can find all such numbers, and then add them together. I'm not too keen on computer science, so I wouldn't know even where to begin. (I'm a math major).

Any help is appreciated. Also any advice on how to compile and run the code would be helpful.

**PS** I know the answer is one of the following: 294185048443, 303141243820, 294095048847, 277319432363, 453190021165, or 210569014847.

Comment: If you prefer Mathematica, you can do `Total[Select[Table[n, {n, 4000000, 5000000}], PrimeQ]]`. This gives the same answer as Yuval's sage code. It's not too smart, but it only takes 0.4 seconds to output the answer on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

```
sage: sum([x for x in range(4000001,5000000,2) if x in Primes()])
294095048847
```

Comment: I don't know whether ``sage`` actually runs a sieve here, but the numbers are so small that this takes only a few seconds.

Comment: Pari:  `t=0; forprime(p=4000000,5000000,t=t+p); t`

Comment: Perl:  
`use Math::Prime::Util "forprimes";
 my $t = 0;  forprimes { $t += $_ } 4e6,5e6;  say $t;`        

or less efficiently:        
`use Math::Prime::Util "primes"; use List::Util "sum";
 say sum(@{primes(4e6,5e6)});`  
                                    
Python:  
`from sympy import sieve
sum([x for x in sieve.primerange(4e6,5e6)])`